# Android google maps directions api find if location is on the way or not

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, location

I have two locations start(A) and destination(B), i am able to get direction lines on map.
Now i have a location (C), is there a way (api) to find if (C) falls in the way from A to B.

Comment: may be [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints) help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you get all the directions from the DIRECTION API from google you'll get the coordinates of each turn too ,just check that your location c coordinates lies in between the directions of the A & B path and click You got your answer.